# List with Sections: Odd Behavior when item in list changes

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a simple Demo App where I present Items in a List with two sections. The first section shows the favourite items, the second section contains the remaining items (which are not favourites).

The odd behaviour occurs if I change the `isFav` state.

on iPhoneOS:

- When I select an item the `DetailView` will appear.
- if I change the `isFav` state (toggle) the `DetailView` will disappear
- [Video](https://youtu.be/Dx_t88YvEVw)

on iPadOS:

- When I select an item the `DetailView` will appear.
- if I change the `isFav` state (toggle) the `DetailView` is   **not** disappearing but in the sidebar, the selection [disappears]
- [Video](https://youtu.be/qq4jQNrqlBg)

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Shared
//
//  Created by Christian on 06.06.21.
//

import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Data Model

struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
   var id = UUID().uuidString
   var isFav = false
   var text: String
}

struct ItemScoped: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
   var id: String {
      return item.id
   }
   var item: Item
   var index: Int
}

//MARK: Store

class ItemStore: ObservableObject {
   @Published var items = [Item(text: "Item 1"),
                           Item(text: "Item 2"),
                           Item(isFav: true, text: "Item 3"),
                           Item(text: "Item 4")]
   
   func scopedItems(isFav: Bool) -> [ItemScoped] {
      let sItems: [ItemScoped]  = items.compactMap {
         guard let idx = items.firstIndex(of: $0) else { return nil }
         //find(items, $0)
         return ItemScoped(item: $0, index: idx)
      }
      return sItems.filter { $0.item.isFav == isFav }
   }
}

//MARK: - Views

struct ContentView: View {
   
   // usally this is @EnvironmetObject, due to simplicity I put it here
   @StateObject var store: ItemStore = ItemStore()
   
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List {
            Section(header: Text("Favorites")) {
               ForEach(store.scopedItems(isFav: true)) { scopedItems in
                  NavigationLink(
                     destination: DetailView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index]),
                     label: {
                        RowView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index])
                     })
               }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Other")) {
               ForEach(store.scopedItems(isFav: false)) { scopedItems in
                  NavigationLink(
                     destination: DetailView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index]),
                     label: {
                        RowView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index])
                     })
               }
            }
         }
         .navigationTitle("Items")
      }
   }
}

// MARK: Row View

/// RowView for item, tapping the text toggle the `isFav` state
struct RowView: View {
   
   @Binding var item: Item
   
   var body: some View {
      Label(
         title: { Text(item.text) },
         icon: { item.isFav ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star")}
      )
   }
}


// MARK: Detail View

/// DetailView to change item `text` and toggle `isFav` state
struct DetailView: View {
   
   @Binding var item: Item
   
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Spacer()
            .frame(height: 20.0)
         TextField("Title", text: $item.text)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .padding(10)
         Toggle("is Fav", isOn: $item.isFav.animation())
            .padding()
         Spacer()
      }
      .padding()
   }
}

// MARK: - Preview

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      ContentView()
   }
}
```

Comment: This behaviour is not odd, it is actually the expected behaviour, because when `isFav` state is changing the `List` is getting updated, and the favourite item is getting removed from the list.

Comment: @cedricbahirwe it is not removed it is only displayed in a another section. Another example would by if the sorting of the list is based on last input date, then every time a user edit the item in "DetailView" the detail view will disappear. An it can't be expected because in iPadOS it behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the `tag` property of the `NavigationLink` and `@SceneStorage` property wrapper.

1. Create a `@SceneStorage` (persistent state per scene)

   ```swift
    @State private var sceneItemID: String?
   ```

   or

   ```swift
    @SceneStorage private var sceneItemID: String?
   ```
2. Add a tag with the unique `id` of the item to every `NavigationLink`

   ```
   NavigationLink(destination:  DetailView(item: $item),
                  tag: item.id,
                  selection: $sceneItemID,
                  label: {
                       RowView(item: $item)
                  })
   ```

   Every time the Navigation Link is used the `sceneItemID` is updated with the `tag` (`item.id` in this case).
3. In the `DetailView` update the `sceneItemID` in the `.onAppear()` modifier.
   This is necessary due to the behaviour during state change of `isFav`.

Now it is working only on iPad the Sidebar does not correctly display the selection. On macOS and iPhone this works.

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Shared
//
//  Created by Christian on 06.06.21.
//

import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Data Model

struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
   var id = UUID().uuidString
   var isFav = false
   var text: String
}

struct ItemScoped: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
   var id: String {
      return item.id
   }
   var item: Item
   var index: Int
}

//MARK: Store

class ItemStore: ObservableObject {
   @Published var items = [Item(id: "uuid01", text: "Item 1"),
                           Item(id: "uuid02", text: "Item 2"),
                           Item(id: "uuid03", isFav: true, text: "Item 3"),
                           Item(id: "uuid04", text: "Item 4")]
   
   /// scope item to sections and keep knowledge of origin index
   func scopedItems(isFav: Bool) -> [ItemScoped] {
      let sItems: [ItemScoped]  = items.compactMap {
         guard let idx = items.firstIndex(of: $0) else { return nil }
         //find(items, $0)
         return ItemScoped(item: $0, index: idx)
      }
      return sItems.filter { $0.item.isFav == isFav }
   }
}


//MARK: - Views

struct ContentView: View {
   
   // usally this is @EnvironmetObject, due to simplicity I put it here
   @StateObject var store: ItemStore = ItemStore()
   
   @SceneStorage("SceneItemSelectionID") private var sceneItemID: String?
   
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         
         List {
            Section(header: Text("Favorites")) {
               ForEach(store.scopedItems(isFav: true)) { scopedItems in
                  NavigationLink(
                     destination: DetailView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index]),
                     //MARK: !! IMPORTANT: use unique indetifier as tag
                     tag: store.items[scopedItems.index].id,
                     selection: $sceneItemID,
                     label: {
                        RowView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index])
                     })
               }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Others")) {
               ForEach(store.scopedItems(isFav: false)) { scopedItems in
                  NavigationLink(
                     destination: DetailView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index]),
                     //MARK: !! IMPORTANT: use unique indetifier as tag
                     tag: store.items[scopedItems.index].id,
                     selection: $sceneItemID,
                     label: {
                        RowView(item: $store.items[scopedItems.index])
                     })
                  
               }
            }
         }
         .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
         .navigationTitle("Items")
      }
   }
}

// MARK: Row View

/// RowView for item, tapping the text toggle the `isFav` state
struct RowView: View {
   
   @Binding var item: Item
   
   var body: some View {
      Label(
         title: { Text(item.text) },
         icon: { item.isFav ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star")}
      )
   }
}


// MARK: Detail View

/// DetailView to change item `text` and toggle `isFav` state
struct DetailView: View {
   
   @Binding var item: Item
   
   @SceneStorage("SceneItemSelectionID") private var sceneItemID: String?
   
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Spacer()
            .frame(height: 20.0)
         TextField("Title", text: $item.text)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .padding(10)
         Toggle("is Fav:", isOn: $item.isFav.animation())
            .padding()
         Spacer()
      }
      .padding()
      .onAppear() {
         //MARK: !! IMPORTANT set scene selction id again
         sceneItemID = item.id
      }
   }
}

// MARK: - Preview

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      ContentView()
   }
}
```

Comment: Added a GitHub Sample Project. (https://github.com/Christian1313/SwiftUISectionList)